# jQuery onchange event, how to ignore too frequently changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I want to implement an auto completion function on my text input, using jQuery by monitoring the change event and query my database on every change.

I know there are some autocompletion plugins but I'm doing something like fuzzy search, so keyword 'ad' may result in words like 'abort' or 'and'. Correct me if I'm wrong, I found most plugins do exact search.

However, I don't want to do database query too frequently, that is, I want to do query only when the text input is updated but haven't been updated for a small amount of time like 200ms. So that I can ignore the constantly high speed inputs by users.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Check out this post. It uses Jquery UI autocomplete and adds fuzzy search to it. It might help. http://www.tomsquest.com/blog/2011/05/better-autocompletes-with-fuzzy-matching/

Comment: @bos570, thanks, I will look into that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like that to make queries.

```
var timeouted=null;
$(e).on('change',function(){
    clearTimeout(timeouted);
    timeouted = setTimeout(function(){
        //database query
    }, 200)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout()` stored as a variable, then on input clear the timeout and reset. If elapsed time is >= desired timeout, make DB query.

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2s1sj6f/7/